# ParseIntError when parsing text file with comma-delimited data?

Tags: rust

I'm having issues parsing comma delimited data in rust. Any ideas?

Text file is as follows,

> 1,2,3,4,5,6

I try to parse this with the following which fails.

```rust
    let contents: String = fs::read_to_string("data.txt").expect("Unable to open file");
    let opcodes: Vec<i32> = contents.split(",").map(|x| x.parse::<i32>().unwrap()).collect();
```

I've modified the above to print `x` for each parse and it seems the result from split looks like it's being used in map as ["1","2","3","4","5","6",""].

**Solution:**

It appears `read_to_string` added a trailing newline. Adding a call to `trim` to before `split` fixes the issue.

```
let opcodes: Vec<i32> = contents.trim().split(",").map(|x| x.parse::<i32>().unwrap()).collect();
```

Answer (score 1):

You answered yourself. `read_to_string` doesn't add a newline arbitrarily. The resulting string contains a newline only if underlying file contains a newline.

To examine how many newlines are present in the `data.txt`, do this

```
cat -t -e data.txt
# you will see meta characters at the end of each line.
```